# How to create a model with mixed regression and classification output in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

In sklearn, there are MultiOutputRegressor and MultiOutputClassifier.
We can use them to output only regression or only classification, but what if we want to output a combination of regression and classification?
Do I need to create separate models?

In tensorflow, we can branch the architecture.
I would like to do regression and classification prediction in one model in this way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would recommend you 'Define your ML problem' first so that the community can propose alternative solutions as you might have got your modeling wrong. I personally think that this question would be better off on https://datascience.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Luke
Thank you for pointing this out.
I asked the question again in the Data Science category.
https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/108277/how-to-create-a-model-with-mixed-regression-and-classification-output-in-sklearn